# Too many redirects with symfony 4

Tags: apache, symfony4

I have published a symfony 4 website which I can visit on the domain without any problems. Most people however, get the error:

> Too many redirects

Reading about this, I believe there is a redirect loop somehow. The problem is, I cannot recreate the issue myself, so I cannot test different solutions. I do not understand why I don't have the issue, while others do. I am using Apache with the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Can you see if there is something wrong? And also, why do I not have the same issue?

**Edit:** another strange thing is: the people that see the error CAN visit the domain by going to www.domain.com/page (where this is an actual page). It's just the homepage they cannot visit directly. When they 'enter' from a different page they can visit the homepage.

**Edit2:** running a test on [www.redirect-checker.org](http://www.redirect-checker.org) this is the result:

> Result
>
> https://www.studiosaam.nl 302 Found /?_locale=de 302 Found
>   /?_locale=de 302 Found /?_locale=de 302 Found /?_locale=de 302 Found
>   /?_locale=de 302 Found /?_locale=de 302 Found /?_locale=de 302 Found
>   /?_locale=de 500 Internal Server Error Problems found:
>
> Too many redirects. Please try to reduce your number of redirects for https://www.studiosaam.nl. Actually you use 8 Redirects. Ideally
>   you should not use more than 3 Redirects in a redirect chain. More
>   than 3 redirections will produce unnecessary load on your server and
>   reduces speed, which ends up in bad user experience.
>       You use a 302 redirect. This means, that the actually content is temporary not reachable and will come back soon. To use a 302
>   redirection for generally moved pages is a bad idea. Search engine bot
>   might not follow it or handle it as temporary. For SEO this is also a
>   bad idea, because no link juice will be transferred to the linked
>   page.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this problem was related to the Symfony config, not Apache. The problem occurred because multiple `locales` were defined in **services.yaml**, but were not actually available. I could not reproduce the problem because my machine's locale is `en` (English), which did not give any errors. Other users with a different `locale` (like `de` for example) entered in a loop where Symfony tried to forward the user to `/?_locale=de` which did not exist therefore were sent back to `/` and then again to `/?_locale=de` etc...

I revolved the problem bu changing the following code in **services.yaml**:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    app_locales: en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN|bg|tr
```

to

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    app_locales: en
```